# Android App Crashing on Bootup

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am new to programming but I want to make an app nonetheless. When I try to run my app using the Debugger in Android Studio, I end up with this error.

```
Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : Unknown     failure (Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires android.permission.ASEC_CREATE permission).
```

I agree to reinstall but this error keeps popping up again and again. Nevertheless, I build the apk and install it anyway and run it that way and I get this in the error logcat

http://dumptext.com/i2GJQw5H

My main concern is that my app is crashing on startup.

Comment: post your xml class and java class also

Comment: can you please share the code?

Comment: XML : http://dumptext.com/hcahYDGK
Java:  http://dumptext.com/PjeQfHdR

Comment: Isn't the log (`Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires android.permission.ASEC_CREATE permission`) clear enough?

Comment: Yes it is. And I tried giving it the uses permission line. Doesn't work.

Comment: That method only works for Android versions before Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it requires ASEC_CREATE permission.

Make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ASEC_CREATE"/>
```

in your `Manifest.xml`

Comment: Not working. It is still showing the same error. It is uninstalling the app but cannot install the app using the debugger.

Comment: Can you disable "Instant Run" and try again?

Comment: It is running, yes. But the app is crashing on start up.